# MongoRepositoryFactory initializing failed when using spring groovy context

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, groovy, spring-data

I'm having trouble creating GenericGroovyApplicationContext with MongoDB configuration. The groovy configuration looks like:

```
package groovy
import com.mongodb.Mongo
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate

beans {
    xmlns([ctx:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context'])
    xmlns([mongoNamespace:'http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo'])

    def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new ClassPathResource('groovy/mongodbconfig.groovy').URL)
    mongo Mongo
    mongoTemplate(MongoTemplate, mongo, config.mongo.dbname)
    mongoNamespace.'repositories'('base-package':'mypackage.data.dao')
}
```

I get the following error (regardless mongoTemplate bean was created):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.getFactoryInstance(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

After debugging I discovered that MongoRepositoryFactoryBean#setMongoOperations was not called while it's calling when using xml spring configuration.
Does anyone have ideas how to fix it? 
Thanks.